# check box not working properly at page load

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox

I have got problem with check-box to enable corresponding control next to it. My Requirement is at the page load we want to disable the all textboxes and dropdownlists by using checkbox 
if the check-box is checked the control next to that check-box will be enabled for that i have done like this....

at page load

i have written like this

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            ChckOrdType.Checked = false;
            ChkPlntPric.Checked = false;
            ChkExcluBro.Checked = false;
            ......
            .....
        }
```

and then in checkbox check changed event i have written like this

```
    protected void ChckOrdType_CheckChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ChckOrdType.Checked)           
            ddlOrdType.Enabled = true;
        else 
            ddlOrdType.Enabled = false;            
    }

    protected void chkPlntPric_CheckChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ChkPlntPric.Checked)
            ddlPlntPric.Enabled = true;
        else
            ddlPlntPric.Enabled = false;
    }

    protected void chkExcluBro_CheckChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ChkExcluBro.Checked)
            ddlExcluBroker.Enabled = true;
        else
            ddlExcluBroker.Enabled = false;       
    }
```

but results is like this ...
I am getting checkbox not checked and control next to it is enabled...But this not what i want

My results is if the check-box is not checked the control next to it is disabled 
would any one pls help on this....
Thanks In advance......

Comment: Are the dropdowns disabled by default?

Comment: no andrei at the page load i need to disable the dropdownlists ...by using checkbox check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you have just wrote ONLY to uncheck the checkboxes in the pageload and not to disable the controls  behind the checkbox; If thats needed, then your snippet in the pageload should be:

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
  ChckOrdType.Checked = false;
  ChkPlntPric.Checked = false;
  ChkExcluBro.Checked = false;
  ......
  .....
  ddlOrdType.Enabled = false; 
  ddlPlntPric.Enabled = false;
  ddlExcluBroker.Enabled = false;  
  .........
}
```

or

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
  ChckOrdType.Checked = false;
  ChkPlntPric.Checked = false;
  ChkExcluBro.Checked = false;
  ......
  .....

  ChckOrdType_CheckChanged(sender,e);
  chkPlntPric_CheckChanged(sender,e);
  chkExcluBro_CheckChanged(sender,e);
  ...
}
```

Comment: if i uncheck the check box it will automatically fire the check changed event right ?

Comment: Nope.. Those are the events which gets triggered when you manually handle the requests/manually check/uncheck the checkboxes..!!! If you want that to happen, then change the pageload event snippet to the one which i've edited..!!

Answer (score 0):

Disable text boxes in page load like below.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            ChckOrdType.Checked = false;
            ChkPlntPric.Checked = false;
            ChkExcluBro.Checked = false;

            DisableFirstTime();
            ......
            .....
        }


private void DisableFirstTime()
{
  ddlOrdType.Enabled = false; 
  ddlPlntPric.Enabled = false;
  ddlExcluBroker.Enabled = false;  
}
```